# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path,zip) Does not work

Tags: c#, console

This is my code.

```
string startPath = @"‪‪C:\Users\batuhan kara\abc";
string zipPath = @"c:\result\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"‪C:\Users\batuhan kara\adc";

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath,zipPath);
```

When I'm debugging Cursor on zip file line the program closed with no errors and no exceptions. I don't know why. I'm using asp.net console app with 4.6.1 framework.

Comment: Do you have permission on folders?

Comment: its not throw exception or anything the program just quit without any error or message. Same code i tried in windows application it works well. But i cant get why it is not working in console app.